# How to update the state varibles all at once in react JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My requirement is from page1 to page2(on form submission) user navigates on some actions. if User navigates to page2 to page1(backward) then all the form fields in page1 should be filled. So i have stored all the data in session but on backward navigation not able to assign all the state values from session.

page1 componentmount code:

```
    componentWillMount() {
        if (sessionStorage.getItem("regData")) {
          let formdata = sessionStorage.getItem("regData");
          JSON.parse(formdata, (key, value) => {
               this.setState({key:value});});
        }
      }

//state variables

    this.state = {
          username: "",
          password: "",
          email: "",
          name: "",
          mobile: "",
          city: "",
          redirectToReferrer: false,
          error: {
            email_error: "",
            password_error: "",
            name_error: "",
            username_error: "",
            mobile_error: "",
            showError: false,
            errorMessage: engTranslations.global.faild
          },
          value: "",
          suggestions: [],
          selectedCity: []
        };
```

Let me know how to assign all state variables at once in component mount method. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to know in which lifecycle the state is supposed to be set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't use the callback for `JSON.parse` (that's a "reviver" function which is to help with deserializing the data). Instead, take the *result* of `JSON.parse` and pass it into `setState`:

```
this.setState(JSON.parse(formdata));
```

More:

- [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)
- [`setState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)
- [Important information for setting state when it's based on other state or props](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous) (yours isn't, so we can just pass an object into `setState`, but many state updates are based on state or props, and for *those*, you have to use the callback form of `setState`)

It's also worth noting that `componentWillMount` isn't the right lifecycle method to be doing this in. Since there's no asynchronous operation involved, the right place would be your constructor, and your constructor is the **one** place you can assign directly to `this.state`, so:

```
constructor() {
    this.state = Object.assign(
        {/*...default state here...*/},
        JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("regData")) // see note
    );
}
```

(If there's no `regData`, `getItem` will return `null`, which will pass through `JSON.parse` [it gets converted to `"null"` and then back to `null`] and ignored by `Object.assign`, so we don't need to have the `if` statement.)

(If there were an asynchronous operation involved, it would be [`componentDidMount`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) and you'd use `setState` instead..)

Comment: I have tried this. it is not working. The values are still empty

Comment: @Cherryg - This is how you do it, so if you're getting blank values, that tells us that something *else* is wrong, such as `regData` not having the structure you think it does. If you show us what the JSON text stored in `regData` is, we may be able to help you, but without all we can do is say "This is how you do it."

Comment: Crowder: Its working.. actually the key and value pair issue. got resolved. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure if I got right the requirement but I guess what you need to do, assuming the session storage value contains all the fields you care of, is instead of doing this:

```
JSON.parse(formdata, (key, value) => {
               this.setState({key:value});});
});
```

Do this:

```
this.setState(JSON.parse(formdata));
```

Also as side notes, take into account that using `componentWillMount` for setting state is considered an anti-pattern(https://vasanthk.gitbooks.io/react-bits/anti-patterns/04.setState-in-componentWillMount.html).

I also think it's not a great idea to store a user password in the session storage.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this, setting state once:-

```
   if (sessionStorage.getItem("regData")) {
        let formdata = sessionStorage.getItem("regData");
        let obj = {};
        JSON.parse(formdata, (key, value) => {
            obj.key = value;
            });
        let newState= {...this.state, ...obj};
        this.setState(newState);
      }
```

Comment: That's not how you use `JSON.parse` and will mangle the data, and that's not how you use `setState`, for multiple reasons. First, it's fine to provide only the state properties you want to update (so no need for `...this.state`), and second, if you *are* supplying state information based on existing state information, you cannot use the object form of `setState`, you have to use a callback.

Comment: this is one of the way you can use json parse :-
https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjson_parse_reviver

Comment: No, it isn't. You're misunderstanding the purpose of the callback. I suggest more reading, perhaps [MDN's page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).

Comment: Okay thanks , i do understand that for this use case it is not needed.

Comment: Not to bang on about it, but the above isn't just "not needed," it's wrong, in two ways: 1. `obj.key = value;` will repeatedly set the property `key` (you probably meant `obj[key] = value;`), and 2. Even if you fix that, the code above completely destroys the structure of the data: http://jsfiddle.net/gpdb6f3c/